# What is a "review" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a *review* said on the following passage?

> Physical activity is being increasingly recognized as an effective tool to treat depression. PhD candidate George Mammen’s **review** published in the October issue of the American Journal of Preventive Medicine has taken the connection one step further, finding that moderate exercise can actually prevent episodes of depression in the long term.

Looking it up on AHDE, it defines it as

> A periodical devoted to articles and essays on current affairs, literature, or art.

However, judging by the context it seems like *review* said here is a single piece of article/essay in the issue of the journal of Preventive Medicine rather than the whole periodical defined in the dictionary.

Comment: http://www.aafp.org/afp/2002/0115/p251.html

Comment: Why did you choose to mention sense 5b given by AHD? And not the relevant sense 5a?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, it didn't occur to me, I thought *work or performance* was connected with something artistic like books, plays, or movies.

Comment: All published writing is considered artistic, except for legal and bureaucratic writing, which is considered the opposite.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm still kind of confused of what a *review* here in this context means. The definition states that it is *A report or essay giving a critical estimate of a work or performance*, but in this article it is saying that George Mammen’s *review* is *finding that moderate exercise can actually prevent episodes of depression in the long term*. There isn't any *estmating of any work or performance*.

Comment: What a _review_ is varies from field to field. In science, a published _review_ is generally a piece of academic writing that reports on and judges professionally another piece of academic writing (typically books -- in which case _book review_ is equivalent -- and less commonly published research articles). In some fields, it may refer to a _literature review_ or _review article_, which summarizes developments in a field over some period of time in some specialized field of study. There are prestigious journals that publish nothing but reviews, like _Mathematical Reviews_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a review is an essay or article which reviews the existing literature or research on a topic in order to suggest a possible consensus among authorities about a particular point.

A graduate student might be expected to perform such a review in order to discover what prior research might have been made on a topic that the student wishes to base his or her own research upon.  A PhD candidate's advisor would likely require such a review, if only to prevent the candidate from researching something that had already been touched upon adequately.  We wouldn't want a PhD candidate to try proving the Phlogiston Theory or something.

Wikipedia says this about "[Literature review](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_review)":

> A literature review is a text written by someone to consider the
>   critical points of current knowledge including substantive findings,
>   as well as theoretical and methodological contributions to a
>   particular topic. Literature reviews are secondary sources, and as
>   such, do not report any new or original experimental work. Also, a
>   literature review can be interpreted as a review of an abstract
>   accomplishment.   Most often associated with academic-oriented
>   literature, such as a thesis or peer-reviewed article, a literature
>   review usually precedes a research proposal and results section. Its
>   main goals are to situate the current study within the body of
>   literature and to provide context for the particular reader.
>   Literature reviews are a staple for research in nearly every academic
>   field.